# Using Angular 11 AsyncPipe only show data when page initiated but missing when refresh the page

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm learning Angular 11 and I got stuck with AsyncPipe, here is my code below:

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AccountService } from '../_Services/_Shared/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public accountService: AccountService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  logout(){
    this.accountService.logout();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }

}
```

Html:

```
<span *ngIf="accountService.currentUser$ | async as user">{{user.UserName}}</span>
```

Service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { auth } from '../../_Models/auth';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })

export class AccountService {

    baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
    private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<auth>(1);
    currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login(model: any){
        return this.http.post<auth>(this.baseUrl + 'Login/Check_Validation_Code', model).pipe(
            map((auth:auth) => {
                if(auth){
                    this.setCurrentUser(auth);      
                }                   
        }));
    }

    setCurrentUser(auth: auth){
        localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(auth));
        this.currentUserSource.next(auth);
    }

    logout(){
        localStorage.removeItem('auth');
        this.currentUserSource.next(undefined);
    }
}
```

The UserName is showing when the page is loaded, but when I refresh the page, it just gone

Am I missing something? or should I fix my code somewhere? please give me a hint! THX!

Comment: You have to set currentUserSource after getting data from local storage on refresh

Comment: Are you sure the `login()` method is triggered when the app is refreshed? Without it being triggered the value isn't emitted to the observable.

Comment: First of all, thx to reply! But is that observable will be singleton when app start? 
I thought it will be there, I can just subscribe it to get the data. So I should always trigger the setCurrentUser function when I need data? I'm confuse about this. thanks!

Comment: Yes, the service is singleton. But refresh is kind of restart and  new singleton service is created. Otherwise you need to store the login info in browser local storage as mentioned by zainhassan.

Comment: @Johnny055279 You must be doing the course "Build an app with ASPNET Core and Angular from scratch" from neil cumming, right?